# How you call someone who reacts and thinks fast

Tags: meaning

If they throw you anything out of the blue and you catch it because you have fast reflects you are...

Comment: I think you mean _reflexes_, not _reflects_.

Comment: Idiomatic ways to ask the question are "*What* do you call someone who reacts and thinks fast?" or "*How* to describe someone who reacts and thinks fast?"

Answer (score 1):

Many options. A few include:

> You are very *responsive.* 
>   You are very *alert.*
>   You are very *reactive*.

[And, a few more here.](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/reacting-quickly-or-strongly)

Alternatively, a simple word *quick* can also work!

> You throw a stone at her out of the blue, and she'll catch it! She's *very quick!*

Comment: I think _quick_ works well, because it can be used for mental quickness, or fast physical reflexes.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the word **deft**, along with any of its synonyms.

> "She deftly answered all the questions thrown at her."